# Changing Frontend UI for an individual user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server

I'm working on a web app and I'm stuck. How do I change UI of my web app from say, In-Review to Ready for Submit, for one individual user?. Is it from server or API?. And if it is, what server/API would I be in need of?, or some third party service?

Comment: There’s nothing here anyone can use to help. We know nothing about your app, infrastructure, what defines the users or their roles/permissions/?, etc.

Comment: please share us How fo you identify the individual user?

Comment: You would presumably grab some sort of unique variable to identify the user (user ID) or group of users (user group?), and then render conditionally based on the value of said variable. You would probably need to grab that info from your back-end with some sort of API call.